# Could someone explain Vives logical notation?

Tags: logic

I'm doing a project on the history of George Boole and wanted some background on how notation has changed through the ages, however do not understand Vives logical notation. Wondering if someone could help me, thank you.

Comment: The [Britannica entry on modern logic](https://www.britannica.com/topic/history-of-logic/Modern-logic) includes some (modest) details of Vives notation, comparing it to others such as Boole.

Comment: See also C.Fantazzi (editor), [A Companion to Juan Luis Vives](https://books.google.it/books?id=BnWpHREb6H0C&pg=PA227), **Vives’s Contributions to Rhetoric and Dialectic**.

Comment: Which notation you mean, and what is your source? His vertical inclusion symbol seems pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Juan Luis Vives (1493–1540)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/vives/) was a Spanish humanist and (like other Humanists : Valla, Ramus) was a harsh critic of medieval formal logic.

Some of his works, relevant for the history of logic are : *Adversus pseudodialecticos* (1520) [see R. Guerlac, [Juan Luis Vives Against the Pseudodialecticians : A Humanist Attack on Medieval Logic, Springer (1979)](https://books.google.it/books?id=BP70CAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) for the English edition] and [*De disciplinis libri XX* (1531)](https://books.google.it/books?id=Rxg8AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA6).

The triangular diagram can be found into : [De censura veri](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=FJbmaidjCk4C&pg=PA171), page 171, regarding *Comparationes* :

> si omne $b$ est $a$, et omne $c$ est $b$, omne $c$ est $a$.